# flutter app crashes on startup after upgrading xCode to the latest version and updating to iOS 17

Tags: iphone, flutter, dart, app-store, ios17

The iOS version of my flutter app was working fine until I updated xCode to the latest version and updated my iPhone to `iOS 17`. now it's working fine on my iPhone.

But when I submit the app to App Store, it's working on my `iOS 17` `iPhone 13 pro`, but it dones't work on previous iOS versions. It craches immediatly on my friend's iPhone who has `iOS 16.7` (iPhone 14 Pro). and also other iPhones.

I updated flutter to the latest version `3.13.6` but ut didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue buy instaling the latest package from github instead of the pub.dev package:

```
  # connectivity_plus: ^4.0.2 #this version (^4.0.2) is not working
  connectivity_plus:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:fluttercommunity/plus_plugins.git
      path: packages/connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus
```

Now this temporary solution is working fine, while waiting for the package team to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to update the connectivity_plus package to the latest version